# Changing AppDelegate file of example I want to use in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appdelegate

Hi all I'm new in creating app for iOS , so sorry if the question stupid a little .
I'm trying to build app where log in to Facebook and getting friend list is only a part, so I want to use the example providing from Facebook to developers , but it have appDelegate file with some methods like this:

---

> ```
> #import "FPAppDelegate.h"
> #import "FPViewController.h"
> @implementation FPAppDelegate
> @synthesize window = _window;
> @synthesize rootViewController = _rootViewController;
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
>  .......
>     return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url]; 
> }
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
>     [FBFriendPickerViewController class];
>     ........
>
>     return YES;
> }
> - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
>     [FBSession.activeSession close];
> }
> ```

---

And it have xib file for FPViewController with h and m files, so what the better way to use this example in my app, I understand that I can't use two appDelegate files, and I trying to change FPAppDelegate that is UIResponder to UIViewController class to push it from some place in my app like this:

```
- (IBAction)loginFacebook:(id)sender
{
        NSLog(@"Facebook");
   delegateViewController *appDelegate = [[delegateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: appDelegate animated:YES];
}
```

where delegateViewController is FPAppDelegate of example I changing to:

```
#import "delegateViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FPViewController.h"
@interface delegateViewController ()
@end
@implementation delegateViewController
@synthesize window2=_window2;
@synthesize rootViewController2=_rootViewController2;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
     ......
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [FBFriendPickerViewController class];
    ......
    self.window2 = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window2.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window2 makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
   ........
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
}
```

but it's not working, so, if I need to change also xib file? Or to change appDelegate file of my project? Or existing another way to use this example in my app? I would like you to explain this to me.

Comment: Where do you instantiate "navigationController?"

You will probably need some code to place the view controller inside of your navigation controller:

navigationController = [[MyNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fbViewController];

But this might not be the only issue.

Comment: I did it , but I hide part of code to not take a lot of place, I don't know how to do scrolling here in questions, so I instantiate my navigationController where I some dots, but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by working through the Apple tutorials so you can understand the UIKit framework to start developing an iOS app.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/Introduction.html

Comment: Sorry, Fruity Geek but I don't find there good answer after deep reading, but thank you